# How do I "clip" or hide the overflow from my circle?

Tags: css

Here I have a section that I am trying to implement a circular border below. The size right now is nice, but the right side overflows (because of `width: 230%` on my `.top-level::after`). The reason why I set the width as such is because of how I want the radius of the circle to be.

Below is my CSS, and the Github link is here: https://github.com/satriapamudji/frontendmentor/tree/main/frontendmentor-03-workitlandingpage

```css
.top-level {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 1440px;
  min-height: 730px;
  background-color: var(--off-white); /* set to transparent */
  z-index: 1;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.top-level::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%; /* horizontally centers the element */
  margin-left: -115%; /* negative half of the width */
  width: 230%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: var(--purple);
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transform: translateY(-15%);
}
```

I have tried:

1. Setting a container for the whole section with `overflow: hidden`. However, if I do this, my hero image gets clipped and the right side still shows.
2. `overflow: hidden` everywhere

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

Why not working with overflow hidden?
check snippet thereafter, it seems to work no?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-level {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 730px;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-level::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  /* horizontally centers the element */
  margin-left: -115%;
  /* negative half of the width */
  width: 230%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transform: translateY(-15%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-level">
</div>
```